# How can I open Poll for Anonymous users?

Tags: 6, polls

I wonder how I can open my poll for everyone including anonymous users, not just registered users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visit admin/user/permissions and check the checkbox for vote on polls for anonymous.

[image]